# How to fix this UIWebview error

Tags: xcode, error-handling, uiwebview

```
Error : Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=101 "(null)"
```

[https://foursquare.com/v/Gran_Hotel_Ciudad_de_México/4c0acaa1a1b32d7f09ff99f0](https://foursquare.com/v/Gran_Hotel_Ciudad_de_M%C3%A9xico/4c0acaa1a1b32d7f09ff99f0)

This was the URL I was trying but the uiwebview gives out the error.

When I executed this code:

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL 
   URLWithString:_webView.request.URL.absoluteString]];
```

It does not open Safari . Infact  I get a blank screen perhaps it's considering the url as NULL string.

So, tell me how to fix this error ?

Comment: I think it is related to the language..but how to get a permanent solution for this problem .